# CSS development for smartphones , tablets etc

Tags: css

Hi I have been usign css for desktop website development for a while now and now I am interested in learning to build websites for a wider range of devices line phones , smatphones , tablets and even consoles that have browsers on them.

Can anyoneone recomend me some book or any other resources that can get me up to date on learning to develop websites for diferent screen resolutions?

Comment: does any of the answers answer your question? Would be nice if you accept any.

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning,

- https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css+mobile+development&safe=active
- http://cssgrid.net/ - a really awesome grid for desktop and mobile
- http://jonathanstark.com/iphone-book

Here are a few resources that might get you on your way!

JMax

Answer (score 0):

**Books**

- [Responsive Web Design](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design) by Ethan Marcotte (the author of the whole "responsive design" movement)
- [Adaptive Web Design](http://easy-readers.net/books/adaptive-web-design/) by Aaron Gustafson

**Video**

- [Luke Wroblewski on Designing for Mobile First](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920020776.do) — really good video course.

**Online inspiration**

- [mediaqueri.es](http://mediaqueri.es/) — go check any website listed in this catalog to see how they achieve the result.